# Please help me to solve the TypeScript Error

Tags: typescript, types

This is error.. Which is show to on change prop using to Text Field. Please help me to Solve the error

> Type '(event: Select Change Event) => void' is not assignable to type
> 'Change Event Handler<HTML Input Element | HTML Text Area Element>'.
> Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
> Type 'Change Event<HTML Input Element | HTML Text Area Element>' is not assignable to type 'Select Change Event'.
> Type 'Change Event<HTML Input Element | HTML Text Area Element>' is not assignable to type 'Change Event'.
> Type 'HTML Input Element | HTML Text Area Element' is not assignable to type 'HTML Input Element'.
> Type 'HTML Text Area Element' is missing the following properties from type 'HTML Input Element': accept, align, alt,
> capture, and 27 2322) (170, 3): The expected type comes from property
> 'on Change' which is declared here on type 'Intrinsic Attributes &
> Library Managed Attributes<Styled Component<(Text Field Props & {
> theme?: Theme | undefined; }) & {}, {}, {}>, ((Text Field Props & { ;
> }) & {}) & {}>'

This Show to implementing on Change

This is the Code I tried:

```
type input Props = {
 

  onChange?: (field: string) => void;
  style?: React.CSSProperties

  
}

interface Item {
  key: string;
  title: string;
}



export default function TextInputField(props: inputProps) {
  
  // ** State
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string>(props.selected || "");

  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
    setValue(event.target.value as string);
    if (props.onChange) props.onChange(event.target.value as string);
  };

  const [title] = useState(props.title);

  
  
    
  return (
    <Box
      component='form'
      noValidate
      sx={{
        display: 'flex'
      }}
      style={{ margin: '10px 0px' }}
    >
      <FormControl
        style={{
          outline: 'none !important',
          width: '100%'
        }}
      >
        {props.select === true ? (
          <StyledField
            value={value}
            type={props.type}
            placeholder={props.placeholder}
            disabled={props.disabled}
            select={props.select}
            size='small'
            title={props.title}
            defaultValue={props.defaultValue}
            onChange={handleChange} [Here OnChange shows the error.]
          >
            {props.options && props.options.length
            ? props.options.map((option, i) => (
                <MenuItem key={i} value={option?.key || ""}>
                  {option?.key === props.selected ? <em>{option?.title}</em> : option?.title}
                </MenuItem>
              ))
            : null}
          </StyledField>
        ) : (
          <StyledFields
            
            type={props.type}
            placeholder={props.placeholder}
            disabled={props.disabled}
            endAdornment={props.endAdornment}
            size='small'
            title={props.title}
            defaultValue={props.defaultValue}
          />
        )}

        <FormHelperText style={{ textAlign: 'right',color: 'rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.5)', fontSize:'12px', fontWeight:'400' }}>{props.helperText}</FormHelperText>
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the line number which throws the error or please create a Minimal, Reproducible problem : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I Have Indicated this